# How to pass a model to AngularJS fileuploader?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-fileupload

I want to upload few files to server with angularjs-file-uploader. I have an array of viewModels, I want to upload files and get the IDs of uploaded files and assign them to corresponding viewModels.

Is there any way to pass my viewModels to fileUploader? Here are the codes I have written so far.

```
 <div ng-if="vm.isFile(v.formItem)" class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="file" name="v.id" nv-file-select uploader="vm.uploader" />
                                                <span class="help-block m-b-none">{{v.formItem.description}}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

I want to pass a "v.formItem" which has a property for uploadedFileId. so that I can assign uploaded file's Id to my Model.

```
 this.uploader = new FileUploader({

            url: 'File/UploadFile',
            autoUpload: true,
            removeAfterUpload: true,
            queueLimit: 1
        });            
this.uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            if (response.success) {
                formItem.uploadedFileId = response.result.id ;

            } 
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just needed to use "options" property for file input. like this:

```
<input type="file" name="v.id" options={formItem:v.formItem} nv-file-select uploader="vm.uploader" />
```

javascript:

```
this.uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers)     {
        if (response.success) {

            var formItem = fileItem.formItem;

            formItem.uploadedFileId = response.result.id ;

        } 
    };
```